# Quota for Google Places API Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I a using Google Places API Web Service, Google Maps Directions API for a project where I am using Google Place Autocomplete for my search query. As of I know, I am supposed to get 2500 requests per day. The project is in testing mode. I am sure I have not searched that limit, but still, I am getting a console error  `You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.`

I am unable to figure out. Can anyone please help me on this issue.
Thanks in advance.

I have added in footer

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=WeddinginitMap">

</script>
```

And my script is:

```
<script>

//Direction Grand Cruise

function initDirection() {
 var $directionMap = $('[ data-directionMap ]');

            $.each($directionMap, function( index, element){

             var $dirEle = $(element);
             var that = $(this);
             var $id = $dirEle.get(0).id;
             var $start = $dirEle.closest('.modal-content').find('.start-move').get(0).id;
             var $end  = $dirEle.closest('.modal-content').find('.end-move').get(0).id;

             //console.log($end);

             var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var map = new google.maps.Map($('#'+$id)[0] , {
          zoom: 18,
          center: {lat: 22.560941, lng: 88.354062}
        });
        var input =  $('#'+$start)[0];


       var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);


        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        $('#'+$start)[0].addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        $('#'+$end)[0].addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);



        function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin: $('#'+$start)[0].value,
          destination: $('#'+$end)[0].value,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);


          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });



      };


            });//end $.each



      };// initDirection



    </script>


<script>
    function WeddinginitMap() {

      var $locationSelector = $('.map-wrapper').find('.location-map[ data-map ]');

      $.each( $locationSelector, function( index, element ){

        var $ele = $(element);
        var $this = $(this);
        var $mapId = $ele.get(0).id;
        var $lat = parseFloat( $('#'+$mapId).data('lat') );
        var $long = parseFloat($('#'+$mapId).data('longi'));
        var $zoom = parseFloat( $('#'+$mapId).data('zoom') );
        console.log($mapId);
        console.log($lat);
        console.log($long);
        console.log($zoom);

        var uluru = {lat: $lat, lng: $long };

        var $map = $('#'+$mapId)[0];
        var map = new google.maps.Map($map, {
          zoom: $zoom,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map,
          icon:'assets/img/svg/vivada-ico.svg'
        });

      });//$.each

 initDirection();

    };
</script>

<script>


     function initializeGoogletMapinsideModal(){
       $('.map-modal ').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

        WeddinginitMap();
        initDirection();

     });

   };
   initializeGoogletMapinsideModal();

   function redirectToDirectionModal(){

    var $closeModal = $('.close-modal');

    $.each( $closeModal, function(index, element ){

     var $elem = $(element);

     $elem.on('click', function(){

        var $MainModal = $elem.closest('.map-modal');
        var $targetDirectionModal = $elem.attr('data-target-modal');

        $MainModal.modal('hide');
        $($targetDirectionModal).modal('show');
        $($targetDirectionModal).on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
           initDirection();
        });

     });//click


    });//$.each


   };

   redirectToDirectionModal()

</script>
```

Comment: Please share what you have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Places API has 1000 daily requests by default

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage

You should be aware that each time when you are typing a new symbol in the autocomplete you are sending a new request. So it is quite easy to exceed 1000 quota using autocomplete element.

You can enable Billing in your project in order to get 150K daily requests for Places API free of charge.

Hope this helps!

#### Update

Please note that Google changes the behavior starting from June 11, 2018. They migrate to Google Maps Platform.

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/product-changes/

Comment: Thanks @xomena for the Update. Will check

Comment: is the daily Places API limit just 1 request per day now? I see that when i log in that is the default value in the qouta limits and seems like i have to enable billing to do more than that. Kinda ridiculous of google to limit to 1 request (for testing would be nice to have 100 per day), but that seems to be the case as me and my friend tested.

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, I did not see any usage from my [dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnVdD.jpg)

I played around the autocomplete list in the search box many times, but I still get no usage record. The quota counts only when one of the place options is selected. I searched through the document and API doc, there is no explanation on how exactly the autocomplete feature is counted. However, I do not agree that it counts as a new request every time user types in a single character. If it does, the quota (1000 per day) will be used up in few minutes and usage will reach the cap easily. Most apps cannot survive.

I would say the autocomplete is counted only when one of the items is picked.

Comment: The quotas are based on the number of requests made to the service. Google's autocomplete widget (referenced by the OP) makes requests to the prediction service while you type and makes a request to get a place when you click on one of the results. Indeed, one user can easily trigger dozens of requests against your quota. (Source: watching the DevTools Network tab plus the Google Developer Console quotas while in development)

Comment: Also, it seems that the daily quota is not a straightforward number of requests. Autocomplete prediction requests count as one-tenth of a request (.1) while selecting one of those predictions counts as 2 requests. Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits#places-api-usage